# How to solve $\alpha,\beta$ in $\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{x}{(1-\alpha x)(1-\beta x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to understand a procedure within solving a generating function problem:

$$G(x) = \dfrac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\dfrac{x}{(1-\alpha x)(1-\beta x)}$$

I understand that the reason for this step is to utilize partial fraction s.t.

$$ =\dfrac{a}{(1-\alpha x)} + \dfrac{b}{(1-\beta x)}$$

I don't know why turning $(1-x-x^2)$ into $(1-\alpha x)(1-\beta x)$ is possible, and is there some formula for this case solving $\alpha$ and $\beta$? The method I'm familiar with is

$$(1-x-x^2)=-(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$$

then I can apply the formula $$r_i=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ but I don't know how to deal with the case $(1-\alpha x)(1-\beta x)$. I need a general method/formula to solve $\alpha$ and $\beta$...

Comment: To utilize  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: It's just factorisation. Always works over the complex numbers.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So this is not related to testing whether $x=0$ is a root (my current idea)?

Comment: If you have $1-x-x^2=-(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$ then $r_1r_2=1$ and then $1-x-x^2=(1-x/r_2)(1-x/r_1)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Oh so since $r_1r_2=1\implies r_1,r_2\not=0$ so I can divide it by $r_1\cdot r_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I understand @Lord Shark the Unknown's comment, it's

$$(1-x-x^2)=-(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$$

then solving for $r_1,r_2=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt5}{2},$ and since $r_1r_2=-1$, simplify to

$$=\dfrac{1}{r_1r_2}(x-r_1)(x-r_2)=(\dfrac{x}{r_1}-1)(\dfrac{x}{r_2}-1)$$

And since $\dfrac{1}{r_1}=-r_2$ and $\dfrac{1}{r_2}=-r_1$,

\begin{align}&=(-r_2x-1)(-r_1x-1)\\
&=(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}x-1)(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}{2}x-1)\end{align}

(But why $1+\sqrt5\over2$ is so strange...?)

Answer (score 1):

If you can factor a quadratic trinomial as

$$(x-\alpha')(x-\beta')$$ then you can also solve for

$$(\alpha x-1)(\beta x-1).$$

Because

$$(\alpha x-1)(\beta x-1)=\alpha\beta\left(x-\frac1\alpha\right)\left(x-\frac1\beta\right)$$

and the roots in the second factorization are the inverses of those in the first one.

In other words,

$$\alpha,\beta=\frac1{\alpha'},\frac1{\beta'}=\frac{2a}{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2c}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $1-x-x^2=0$ has two real roots, which are$$\alpha=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\beta=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2},$$We can denote$$1-x-x^2=-(x-\alpha)(x-\beta).$$Thus, we may assume $$\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{A}{x-\alpha}+\frac{B}{x-\beta}.\tag1$$
Multiply $x-\alpha$ to the both sides of $(1)$ and then let $x=\alpha$. We have$$A=\frac{\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}.$$Likewise, multiply $x-\beta$ to the both sides of $(1)$ and then let $x=\beta$. We have$$B=\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\beta}.$$As a result,$$\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{\alpha}{(\beta-\alpha)(x-\alpha)}+\frac{\beta}{(\alpha-\beta)(x-\beta)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: we have $$1-x-x^2=1-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta x^2$$therefore $$\begin{cases}\alpha+\beta=1\\\alpha\beta=-1\end{cases}$$can you finish now?